# Performing PCA on multistate variables (vector rather than scalar values)

Tags: pca, bioinformatics

I have a data set of individuals genotyped over thousands of polymorphic (variable) loci. At each locus, each individual has two nucleotides from the set {A,C,G,T}, either a pair of identical nucleotides e.g. A/A or two different nucleotides e.g. C/G

So each individual has the following data structure, e.g. for the first 3 loci of the first individual, we may have something like

```
               A   C   G   T
     Locus1    2   0   0   0
     Locus2    0   0   0   2
     Locus3    0   1   1   0
     ...etc
```

while individual 2 may be

```
               A   C   G   T
     Locus1    0   2   0   0
     Locus2    0   0   1   1
     Locus3    0   1   1   0
     ...etc
```

I have ~200 genotyped individuals in the data set, and I'm trying to determine the best way to perform a PCA on this data set. One approach I tried was (for each site) to select the most common nucleotide, so that each individual is characterized by a frequency 1, 1/2, 0 based on whether the nucleotide is present or absent at that site. However, this discards information about all but the most common allele at each locus.

Is there a standard way to perform PCA where each variable isn't a single numerical value but rather a multistate variable like the example above, so that I can leverage information about all of the possible states rather than reducing it to a PCA on the frequency of the most common allele at each site?

A related problem occurs if I subdivide my 200 individuals into regional subpopulations, so that rather than nucleotide counts for each individual, I do so for every subset, so that at some loci there are non-zero values for each nucleotide. In that case in particular, using the frequency of the most common nucleotide in order to provide a single state measurement at each locus loses a lot of information.

What I'm looking for is how to perform PCA on a set of measurements where each measure is vector rather than scalar-valued.

Comment: Let me ask what you want to achieve in the result, what is your goal? Why do you think PCA is what is needed?

Comment: I would like to determine where individuals and sub-populations fall in multivariate gene frequency space. If each locus were a scalar value, PCA would be the most straightforward way of reducing the dimensionality to 2-3 variables.

Comment: Don't sure I accurately understand what you want. Why not see your data as cases=individuals, variables=loci, possible values (categorical)= AA, CC, GG, TT, AC, AG, AT, CG, CT, GT. Then perform multiple correspondense analysis (MCA) which is an analogue of PCA, but for categorical data.

Comment: Note that in the second part of my post, I mention that I have 5 subpopulations. For each locus, I have a vector of counts of every nucleotide, i.e. the number copies of A,C,G,T in each subpopulation. Thus every measurement (corresponding to the L loci) is a vector rather than a scalar. I don't see an immediate way to analyze this using PCA, nor would MCA work because I have numeric rather than categorical measurements associated with every vector.

Comment: You have observations (individuals, they potentially could be grouped ib subpopulations) and two kinds of variables which are crossed - sites and nucleotides. This a 3D dataset. It should be first somehow restructured or reconsidered into a 2D (usual) dataset. What are your "primary" variables - associations between which would define the space reduction? Are these sooner the sites ot the nucleotides?